# Ubuntu 17.10 installer doesn't recognize partitions

Tags: system-installation, partitioning

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 17.10 as a secondary OS but i don't have enough free space so in the Ubuntu installer i resized a partition from 210 to 180 GB and i chose "do not use it" from the resizing menu so it just turned the 30 GB's to unallocated space but i couldn't allocate it in the installer to install the OS on it , so after restarting i allocated it using the windows Disk Manager to a NTFS partition.
but when i tried to install Ubuntu again it didn't recognize all the partitions except the \C (i saw the \C partition alone and the rest of the disk are on one partition with about 400 GB capacity).
Another question , will the option in the resizing menu in the installer determines what to do with the resized partition or with the free space that 
is left after resizing ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Does windows show the disk as "basic" or "dynamic", Ubuntu can't use dynamic disks.

Comment: it shows dynamic

Comment: it needs to be a basic disk. changing will likely require reinstalling windows.

Comment: so there's no other solution , even if i chose to install ubuntu instead of windows automatically in the installer ?

Comment: If you don't want windows, let the installer use the whole disk. Windows Dynamic disk is similar to an Extended partition in that it is a container partition with logical volumes inside; however, Ubuntu can't read these volumes because Windows doesn't release the specs.